# geetting error while running ionic crosswalk integration

Tags: android, crosswalk-runtime

i am new to ionic framework, i was unable to get the inspect elements when i debug my application on my android mobile, so i tried installing  crosswalk
with the following steps

```
npm install -g ionic
ionic platform add android
ionic browser add crosswalk
```

i had followed the steps and even tried uninstalling the application and reverting the crosswalk, but the error remains same. this is the error which i am facing.

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processArmv7DebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 41.063 secs

G:\GTM\Ionic\ionic programs\recipes\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.j
s:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s /c ""G:\GTM\Ionic\ionic programs\rec
ipes\platforms\android\gradlew" cdvBuildDebug -b "G:\GTM\Ionic\ionic programs\re
cipes\platforms\android\build.gradle" -PcdvBuildArch=arm -Dorg.gradle.daemon=tru
e"
ERROR running one or more of the platforms: Error: cmd: Command failed with exit
 code 1
You may not have the required environment or OS to run this project
```

can anyone help me with this error.
thanks in advance.